# Show Logic Equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

$(A \wedge (B \vee C) \implies (A \wedge C) = \neg A \vee \neg B \vee C$

Attempt:

$\neg(A \wedge (B \vee C)) \vee A \wedge C$, by $(x \implies y) \equiv (\neg x \vee y)$

$\neg A \vee \neg(B \vee C) \vee A \wedge C$, by De Morgan's law

$\neg A \vee \neg B \wedge \neg C \vee A \wedge C$, by De Morgan's law

.....

How could I simplify it to $\neg A \vee \neg B \vee C$..

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Typically, one should refrain from using ALL CAPS as it appears you are yelling.

Comment: You are dropping parentheses that are still required. $\vee$ and $\wedge$ distribute over each other, so you have to specify the order in which they must be performed. Without the appropriate parentheses, your statements are not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $x \rightarrow y \equiv \neg(x \wedge \neg y)$.

$\neg(A \wedge (B \vee C) \wedge \neg(A \wedge C))$

$\neg(A \wedge (B \vee C) \wedge (\neg A \vee \neg C))$

Use $A \wedge (\neg A \vee \neg C) \equiv A\wedge\neg(C)$

$\neg(A \wedge (B \vee C) \wedge \neg C)$

Use the same property on $(B \vee C) \wedge \neg C$.

$\neg(A \wedge B \wedge \neg C)$

Use De Morgan's law:

$\neg A \vee \neg B \vee \neg \neg C \equiv \neg A \vee \neg B \vee C$

Comment: May I ask how you got "A∧(¬A∨¬C)≡A∧¬(C)"

Comment: I assume you used commutative law to get 
¬((B∨C) ∧ A ∧ (¬A∨¬C)) after this you used distributive law to get:
A∧¬A ∨ A ∧¬C . Here A∧¬A becomes A and then A ∨ A ∧ ¬C
becomes A ∧ ¬C ??